# Unknown character inserted into xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

In my software, read user information from active directory in c# and inserted into xml file.

My xml syntax should be:

```
<user identifier="williams">
  <password>123456</password>
  <email>-----@gmail.com</email>
  <assignRole>DomainUsers</assignRole>
</user>
```

My software hosted on a intranet server and many client user my asp.net site.All client go to my registration page , See user profile and agree with them.When user click on agree button , User AD information inserted in a xml file for example security.xml.Today I have problem , In my xml file inserted user information with "?" character :

```
<user identifier="williams">
  <password>123456</password ?
  <email>-----@gmail.com</email>
  <assignRole>DomainUser?</assignRole ?
</user>
```

Anybody can explain why inserted "?" character in my file?

Is it possible clients have a direct impact on  my software?

Comment: This problem for many user,my software register 150 user information with no problem , but many user install special font and for these users my registration module is failed ,because inserted "?" character.

Comment: Post the code where you are creating the XML.

Answer (score 0):

look at specifying encoding type for the xml... the ? means that the encoding type used in the XML cannot read a specific character. Like é ...

You can either:

Specify encoding type and force it at the XML level.

Or

Convert the string to a specific encoding before putting it into the XML.

Comment: my encoding is UTF-8 and why many users successful registration and many user does not ?

Comment: depends on which charaters are being inserted... if for most there is no special characters inserted, it'll work fine... for those that this is not true, it will cause major problems. We, at my work, had even more issues when we specified the encoding for the XML Schema on TOP of all of that... then we had 3 places to check for proper encoding... so we removed all that and used UTF16 everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  to store data like html characters and any other stuff that is not plain text :)

in example :

```
<user identifier="williams">
   <password>123456</password ?
   <email><![Cdata[-----@gmail.com]]></email>
   <assignRole>DomainUser?</assignRole ?
</user>
```